# How to check NEW value exists in BEFORE UPDATE Trigger Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table Demo:

```
create table Demo (
   id int(10) auto_increment primary key,
   text varchar(30) default null,
   istrue boolean default false
);
```

I want create a update trigger such that:

When `Update Demo set istrue = false where id = 1;` (not "set text = ") -> normal update.

When `Update Demo set text= 'abc' where id = 1;` ("set text = ") -> `SET NEW.text := concat(OLD.text,'#', NEW.text);`

I have implemented trigger as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_text 
    BEFORE update ON Demo
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF (exists(SELECT NEW.text)) THEN -- how to check NEW.text exists???
        SET NEW.text := concat(OLD.text,'#', NEW.text);
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But it isn't working! Please help. Thank You!!! (My English is not good. Hope everyone sympathized)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER update_text 
BEFORE update 
ON Demo
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.text = CASE WHEN OLD.text <=> NEW.text
                    THEN NEW.text
                    ELSE CONCAT(OLD.text, '#', NEW.text)
                    END;
```

PS. Single-statement trigger - BEGIN-END and DELIMITER reassing not needed.

---

After the deep investigation I have found the way to detect that the field value was set in UPDATE statement.

However, I can't guarantee its reliability. I only check does the substring `` '`text`' `` is present in current query text - but there is a lot of situations when this check will give errorneous result, for example, wrong TRUE if this substring is a part of new value, or wrong FALSE if the fieldname is not wrapped with backticks. So be aware.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER update_text 
BEFORE update 
ON demo
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.`text` = CASE WHEN LOCATE('`text`', ( SELECT info 
                                              FROM information_schema.processlist 
                                              WHERE id = CONNECTION_ID() 
                                            )
                                 )
                    THEN CONCAT(OLD.`text`, '#', NEW.`text`)
                    ELSE NEW.`text`
                    END;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=28e24ef786f4109f5157c59bd2bf8db4)

Comment: It work! But in case:
id | text | istrue
------------------
1  | abc | 0
------------------
2  | qwe | 1
. Execute`Update Demo set text= 'abc' where id = 1;`. 
I want result is: 'abc#abc' 
Is it possible?

Comment: @SơnNguyễn The answer updated. Look - maybe it is safe for you? Nevertheless it must be checked carefully.

Comment: Oh great! Thank you so much. Although in some cases it may not work properly. But I still think this is a good solution !!!

Comment: @SơnNguyễn You may alter the subquery which checks current query text provided from `information_schema.processlist` table and use complex LIKE condition which compares both field name and the value. But the current query text is provided literally and may NOT alter direct compare (for example, new value `'bbb'` will not be found in the variant `SET text = REPEAT('b', 3)`).